# values for which there is a boundary layer for BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-layer

Consider
$$ \epsilon y'' + x^{\alpha} y' + y = 0 , \; \; \; \; \epsilon \to 0^+ $$

with $y(0)=y(1)=1$. For what value of $\alpha$ there is boundary layer at $x=0$? What is the thickness of the boundary layer?

### Try:

I know there is a boundary layer near $x = 0$ if $x^{\alpha} >0 $ which means that we want $\alpha = 2k $ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Im stuck on trying to find the thickness of the BL

Answer (score 0):

As $x^α>0$ for any $x>0$, there is no special demand on $α$.

You need to balance for $Y(X)=y(\delta X)$
$$
ϵY''(X)+δ^{α+1}X^αY'(X)+δ^2Y(X)=0
$$
so that you have to consider the cases $α+1<2$, $α+1>2$ and $α+1=2$.